# Google "Appears in public search results" option greyed out

Tags: google-drive

For a Google Drive file I want to make publicly available, I see these options:

[image: Google Options - Screenshot]

The "Appears in public search results" option is greyed out. What can I do to select/check it?

Comment: did you apply the security update?

Comment: @zucc0nit: Yes tried what I believe were all possible permutations: turning on and off, same with folder.

Comment: Google Docs and Google Drive *does not* give you the option to find public files

Comment: This looks to be an off-topic question for [su]. [tag:google-drive] should be used only for questions about a deprecated client, there is no proper tag here for the Google Drive web app as it's off-topic. It might be on-topic in [webapps.se] but it hasn't enough details and it's too old to be migrated.